# WatchOS warning: rejected resignFirstResponder when being removed from hierarchy

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-watch, watchos, wkinterfacecontroller

I'm getting this error in Xcode.

> `2018-02-26 07:13:22.326888-0500 Watch Extension[1298:2691330] [View]
>   First responder warning: '<SPInterfacePicker: 0x14dc1740; frame = (76
>   0; 58 44); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x14dcd8a0>; layer =
>   <CALayer: 0x14dc1910>>' rejected resignFirstResponder when being
>   removed from hierarchy`

My InterfaceController has 4 `WkInterfacePicker`s and it seems like this error might be related to presenting an alert (when the user saves data), but I am not sure.

Has anyone else ever seen this?

**My code:**

```
if successSaving == true {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.success)
        self.showSuccessAlertWith(message: "Workout Saved, Stats Added.")
    }

    func showSuccessAlertWith(message: String){

        let action1 = WKAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) {
            WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: ["InterfaceController"],
                                                                            contexts: nil,
                                                                            orientation: .vertical,
                                                                            pageIndex: 0)
        }
        presentAlert(withTitle: "Success", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert, actions: [action1])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what is happening is that `WKInterfacePicker`s are very easy to accidentally leave in a "still editing" state, in other words if you scroll through the values then tap "Done" button (which calls `reloadRootPageControllers`) the system thinks the user was still in the process of editing the picker's value.

I can just ask users to be more careful (unlikely)...but I am unsure how to solve which in iOS the equivalent would be calling `resignFirstResponder.` 
Neither `resignFocus` nor setting `isActive` to false, according to my testing, prevent this message from logging.